# How to set active class on clicked button only using Angular6?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I have 3 buttons in a row. I want to set active class on clicked button only but problem is when i clicked another button after one button so it is setting active class on all buttons.

Set active class is not working correctly. All buttons get active class when clicked. If i will click on 2 buttons it will set active class on both button when clicked.

Here is my code at stackblitz

[StackBlitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxzinx)

i want to set active class only on clicked button at a time not on all the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can do this more easy, with angular dom features.

You can show here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s8suc8?file=src/app/app.component.ts

it is a sample that I think that you want, but I think that you can do it better:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmzijo?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

as far as i can understand you need to toggle on active and inactive status:

This is the new plunker , have a look if it solves the issue:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzxhkv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I have removed     `event.srcElement.classList.add('phase-active')` which was responsible for applying `phase-active` on every button

Comment: it is still not working correctly.  Please see carefully on your result. If you will click in button "P-I" so button gets red but when you will click on button "P-II" after click on "P-I" so both buttons will get active class.

Comment: Now I got your point ...I have updated the stackblitz; solving the issue